# Ruby - newlines and operators

Tags: ruby, operators

Consider the following code:

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = (y + x)

puts z
```

As you'd expect, the output is `9`. If you introduce a newline:

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = y
+ x

puts z
```

Then it outputs `5`. This makes sense, because it's interpreted as two separate statements (`z = y` and `+x`).

However, I don't understand how it works when you have a newline within parentheses:

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = (y
+ x)

puts z
```

The output is `4`. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Ruby programmer at all. This is just a wild guess.)

With parens, you get `z` being assigned the value of

```
y
+x
```

Which evaluates to the value of the last statement executed.

Comment: +1. I was trying to explain the basic concept of unfinished commands when I realized that the output was 4, not 9. Good going :)

Comment: That makes lots of sense. I was coming from the same example in Scala where it treats it as z = (y+x) and outputs 9. Good explanation :-)

Comment: Multiline parentheses are essentially a block, and the block's value is the last statement in it.

Answer (score 4):

End the line with \ in order to continue the expression on the next line.  This gives the proper output:

```
x = 4
y = 5
z = (y \
  + x)
puts z
```

outputs 9

I don't know why the result is unexpected without escaping the newline.  I just learned never to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Well you won't need the escaping character `\` if your lines finishes with the operator

```
a = 4
b = 5
z = a +
    b

puts z 
# => 9
```

Comment: I use this technique to end a line with a dot if I'm chaining together a bunch of methods.